# OpenSSH Not listed as a Windows capability

Tags: windows-10, openssh

I'm trying to install OpenSSH on my Windows 10 machine, and upon attempting to follow the usual instructions (like those found [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server)) I was unable to see OpenSSH as an option to install. When I tried to download the file and install through PowerShell, I got the error message:

> install-ssh.ps1: The term 'install-sshd.ps1' is not recognized...

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

[image: Powershell error]

[image: Absence of OpenSSH in the menu]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 is that? What HW? + For the `install-ssh.ps1`: You have to run the commend, from the folder, where you have extracted the OpenSSH package to.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 pro 1703, and I did run the command from the appropriate folder.

Comment: You are execute the command in `C:\Windows\System32`. Are you sure you have extracted the OpenSSH package there? 1) You should not modify `System32` folder. 2) The article suggests using `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH`.

Answer (score 1):

The [article you refer to yourself](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server#win10) clearly says that the OpenSSH is available as an optional feature on Windows 10 **1803** and newer.

You should update your Windows 10 installation.